# Google Analytics sessions are not shown in reports for iOS App

Tags: android, ios, google-analytics

I have just added an app on google analytics to test the SDK and reporting. But I am unable to see the sessions. I have followed the [google's implementation guid.](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/)

I have added the required frameworks, initialized the tracker. Here is my `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    // Optional: automatically send uncaught exceptions to Google Analytics.
    [GAI sharedInstance].trackUncaughtExceptions = YES;

    // Optional: set Google Analytics dispatch interval to e.g. 20 seconds.
    [GAI sharedInstance].dispatchInterval = 2;

    // Optional: set Logger to VERBOSE for debug information.
    [[[GAI sharedInstance] logger] setLogLevel:kGAILogLevelVerbose];

    // Initialize tracker. Replace with your tracking ID.
    [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:@"UA-56974161-1"];
    id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];
    tracker.allowIDFACollection = YES;

    return YES;
}
```

I have done this in my `ViewController`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];

    [tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createEventWithCategory:@"Played"     // Event category
                                                          action:@"Pressed"  // Event action
                                                           label:@"Finish"     // Event label
                                                           value:nil] build]];    // Event value

    // Enable Advertising Features.
    tracker.allowIDFACollection = YES;
    [tracker set:kGAIScreenName value:@"BarrenFields"];

    [tracker send:[[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createScreenView]
                    set:@"Barren Fields"
                    forKey:[GAIFields customDimensionForIndex:1]] build]];

    NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            @"appview", kGAIHitType, @"Home Screen", kGAIScreenName, nil];
    [tracker send:params];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

Now may be I have missed something. Can anyone figure it out?

Comment: what u tried in analytics u want to measure the screen or get the event tracking

Comment: I am trying to get both